# jQuery totalStorage - Get all keys

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using jQuery totalStorage and wanted to find out how I can loop through all items stored in total storage.

Something like this:

```
var itemCount = $.totalStorage.length;

for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
    var element = $.totalStorage[i];
    // do something here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.getAll()` method

```
var all = $.totalStorage.getAll();
$.each(all, function(idx, obj){
    console.log(obj.key)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of something like [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
$.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
  alert( key + ": " + value );
});
```